# Adolescent Architecture problem on Kattis

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have some difficulties in solving [this](https://open.kattis.com/problems/adolescentarchitecture) problem on kattis.

However I did try it and got wrong answer. This is what I did. Firstly I sorted the given shapes in ascending order according to the given dimension of their surface, to do this there are two things to consider when comparing two shapes:

1. If the surface shapes are same, then compare the dimensions directly.
2. If the surface shapes are different (square vs circle), then I compare the diagonal side of the square with the diameter of the circle. [image to help visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0T8N.png)

Then for each two adjacent shapes (let them be S[i] and S[j], where i = j - 1) in the sorted array, I checked if it was possible to keep them on top of each other (can S[i] be placed on top of S[j]). To do this we must consider three things:

1. If Cylinder on Cube, then check if diameter of cylinder <= length of side of cube
2. Cube on Cylinder, then check if diagonal of square (surface of cube) <= diameter of cylinder
3. If same Shapes, then check if dimension of S[i] <= dimension of S[j]
   [image to help visualize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPomu.png)

If there exist any i and j where i = j - 1 such that S[i] and S[j] does not follow the above rules then I just say it's impossible to stack them.

To find the diagonal of the square I used. diagonal = Sqrt(2) * (length of side).

Here is my code, it was done in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#define ROOT_2 1.41428571429

bool cube_on_cylinder(int dCb, int dCy) { //test if cube can be placed on cylinder
  return ROOT_2 * dCb <= 2 * dCy;
}

bool cylinder_on_cube(int dCy, int dCb) { //test if cylinder can be placed on cube
  return 2 * dCy <= dCb;
}

bool shapeA_on_shapeB(char *shapeA, int dA, char *shapeB, int dB) { // test if shapeA can be placed on shapeB
  if(shapeA[1] == shapeB[1]) return dA <= dB;
  if(shapeA[1] == 'u') return cube_on_cylinder(dA, dB);
  return cylinder_on_cube(dA, dB);
}

bool shapeA_gt_shapeB(char *shapeA, int dA, char *shapeB, int dB) {
  if(shapeA[1] == shapeB[1]) return dA > dB;
  if(shapeA[1] == 'u') return ROOT_2 * dA > 2 * dB;
  return 2 * dA > ROOT_2 * dB;
}
int main() {
  int n, *ds;
  char **shapes;
  std::cin >> n;
  ds = new int[n];
  shapes = new char*[n];

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    shapes[i] = new char[8];
    std::cin >> shapes[i] >> ds[i];
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // sorting
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if(shapeA_gt_shapeB(shapes[i], ds[i], shapes[j], ds[j])) {
        char *tempShape = shapes[i];
        shapes[i] = shapes[j];
        shapes[j] = tempShape;
        int tempD = ds[i];
        ds[i] = ds[j];
        ds[j] = tempD;
      }
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0, j = 1; j < n; i++, j++) {
    if(!shapeA_on_shapeB(shapes[i], ds[i], shapes[j], ds[j])) {
      std::cout << "impossible";
      return 0;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cout << shapes[i] << " " << ds[i] << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried the above method but did not work when I uploaded it.

Comment: Your sorting is wrong; the "cylinder vs cube" conditions should not be the same.

Comment: @molbdnilo, how should the sorting be done then? I thought the shape that protrudes more when viewed from the top should "be greater" than that of the shape that doesn't.

Comment: It should. The condition for "cube on cylinder" and "cylinder on cube" are not the same, but you're using the cube's diagonal for both cases. (Compare your ordering to your `cylinder_on_cube` and `cube_on_cylinder` functions.)